# Why would a mysql SELECT with 'LIKE word%word2' in the where clause not use an index

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-like

The query is large and includes a long list of  'LIKE' tests in the WHERE clause, e.g., ...SELECT colA FROM t WHERE (colX LIKE 'word1%word2%' OR colX LIKE 'word3%word4%' OR...);

colX has an index.  mysql uses the index since the comparison doesn't start with a '%'. By checking with EXPLAIN I see that when the SQL string gets bigger mysql stops using the index and starts doing full table scans.  It seems to be related to the number of 'LIKE' tests in the where clause. At the threshold I can add one more 'LIKE' and it stops using the index and takes 10 times longer than without the extra 'LIKE'.

Is there some mysql variable that controls behavior like this?

Comment: What if you rewrite your query to do `UNION` s instead of `OR` s do you still get the same behaviour?

Comment: Splitting up into UNIONs causes the indexes to be used.  I had to cut the long list of LIKEs into quarters to get it to use the index so it seems to have something to do with the number of LIKEs.  Performance is now noticeably better. Any idea why the optimizer would behave so much worse if there are a lot of LIKEs?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you add `FORCE INDEX [index_name]`, it will use index in any case. Also, check [Hint index documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html). The value of [sysvar_max_seeks_for_key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_seeks_for_key) also affects whether the index is used or not. Maybe changing this value to a smaller number will help.